# How to override system commands in shells initiated by Perl?

Tags: perl, bash, gnuplot

I am trying to install `CPAN` modules on shared Linux environment **without root privileges**, and in particular the `PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot` module. The default gnuplot version is `Version 3.7 patchlevel 3`, but the version `Version 4.6 patchlevel 3` is also installed (`/opt/gnuplot-4.6.3/bin/gnuplot`). When trying to install the Perl module in my local directory, it fails on the test:

```
unless(`gnuplot -V`)
```

I tried to override the default gnuplot command with an alias in `.bashrc`:

```
alias gnuplot='/opt/gnuplot-4.6.3/bin/gnuplot'
```

In the regular shell I get:

```
$gnuplot -V
gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 3
```

But using Perl:

```
$ perl -e 'system("gnuplot -V")'
         Cannot open load file '-V'
         line 0: (No such file or directory)
```

How do I make Perl to see the new version of gnuplot?

On solution I think of is to change the system command in the `Makefile` and in the following files in the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell aliases only work in the interactive shell. You have other options:

1. Change your PATH so that the newer gnuplot's `bin` precedes the old one.
2. Make a symbolic link to the new gnuplot from your `bin` and make sure it comes first in PATH.